# Single IMDB scrape returns desired text but applying to entire list returns "character empty"

Tags: r, web-scraping, xpath, rvest

I am learning the rvest package

I am able to scrape the Link URL of a list item as a singular item

```
website <- "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&genres=crime"

page <- read_html(website)

xpath_expression <- '/html/body/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[3]/section/section/div/section/section/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a'

link_url <- html_attr(html_node(page, xpath = xpath_expression), "href")
```

However, if I want to scrape all the 50 link URLS from the first part of the list, it returns only "character empty. I tried to identify them via xpath and extract it from there

```
website <- "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&genres=crime"
page <- read_html(website)

xpath_expression <- '//*[@id="main"]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/h3/a'

link_nodes <- html_nodes(page, xpath = xpath_expression)
```

link_urls <- html_attr(link_nodes, "href")

Comment: it seems like the issue is with your xpath. Dunno where the second xpath came from, or why you thought it would work. However something like this works: `page |> html_nodes(".ipc-title-link-wrapper") |> html_attr("href")`

Answer (score 1):

1. By using `[3]` as predicate's you are telling the XPath-engine to only use a `div` that has a `position()=3`. And therefore probably work for 1 item, but not for all.
2. There does not seem to be a element with @id='main'. So that's the reason why your 2e XPath returns no result.

Try the following XPath:

```
//li[@class='ipc-metadata-list-summary-item']//a[@class='ipc-title-link-wrapper']
```

It uses classes that will probably not change